# Setting margin between div rectangle and text inside

Tags: html

I am trying to put some margin space between the borders of my rectangle div and the text inside. I can't figure out a way to do the same. My HTML code looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
        }

        table {
          /* The image used */
          background-image: url("<someimagelink>");

          /* Full height */
          /*height: 100%;*/ 

          /* Center and scale the image nicely */
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor='#B3B6B7'>
    <table class="container" width=800px align='center' cellpadding="5">


        <tr align='justify' style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:black; font-size:14pt'>

            <td class="content" width=80% style='padding: 30px 30px;'>

        <div style="width:750px;height:300px;margin: 20px;background-color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid black;opacity: 0.6;">
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum felis sit amet eros fringilla, vel hendrerit metus pharetra. Morbi massa libero, dapibus interdum vehicula quis, commodo id dui. Phasellus quis tempus lacus. Nulla cursus sed mi malesuada tempus. Mauris blandit ligula ligula, eu placerat libero semper nec. Morbi eget ipsum volutpat, pellentesque enim sit amet, egestas odio. Nam id sapien laoreet, interdum lectus sit amet, fermentum felis. Nullam dui ligula, vulputate accumsan varius id, pulvinar at neque. Curabitur est metus, molestie ut sapien sit amet, finibus rutrum turpis. Nunc id porttitor lectus. Cras erat eros, congue eu eros eu, dapibus facilisis urna. Ut eu consequat felis, eget sollicitudin justo. Aenean vulputate risus eget tempus imperdiet. Nulla ligula purus, tincidunt id tristique et, commodo a elit. 
        </p>
      </div>
       </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to keep the table structure intact and cannot break away from that. This is what the output [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZGWV.png)

Any help on putting margin between the left and right borders and the inside text will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `padding` on that DIV, for example `padding: 10px;`